# How to automatically crop each small window from a zoom picture?

Tags: python, image, crop, opencv

Is there a way to automatically crop each window from a screenshot ? Zoom windows can have multiple small windows like  the below examples. I tried cv2 and able to do it if I know how many small window are there . Just want to know if there is a way to automatically identify how many small windows are there .

[image: 3 x 3]

[image: 2 X 2]

Or Very odd unsymmetrical windows

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look up "edge detection". Each image has a contrasting border around it, so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I tried following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169645/square-detection-in-image , it is not working for the kind of images that I have . Trying other options.