# Detect squares (paintings) in images and draw contour around them using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I'm trying to detect and draw a rectangular contour on every painting on for example this image:

[image]

I followed some guides and did the following:

1. Grayscale conversion
2. Applied median blur
3. Sharpen image
4. Applied adaptive Threshold
5. Applied Morphological Gradient
6. Find contours
7. Draw contours

And got the following result:

[image]

I know it's messy but is there a way to somehow detect and draw a contour around the paintings better?

Here is the code I used:

```
path = '<PATH TO THE PICTURE>'

#reading in and showing original image
image = cv2.imread(path)
image = cv2.resize(image,(880,600)) # resize was nessecary because of the large images
cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

# grayscale conversion
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("painting_gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

# we need to find a way to detect the edges better so we implement a couple of things
# A little help was found on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169645/square-detection-in-image 
median = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
cv2.imshow("painting_median_blur", median) #we use median blur to smooth the image
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

# now we sharpen the image with help of following URL: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/sharpening-an-image-using-opencv-library-in-python/ 
kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0],
                [-1, 5,-1],
                [0, -1, 0]])
image_sharp = cv2.filter2D(src=median, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel)
cv2.imshow('painting_sharpend', image_sharp)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# now we apply adapptive thresholding
# thresholding: https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding 
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(src=image_sharp,maxValue=255,adaptiveMethod=cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                            thresholdType=cv2.THRESH_BINARY,blockSize=61,C=20)   
cv2.imshow('thresholded image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# lets apply a morphological transformation
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
cv2.imshow('dilated image', gradient)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



# # lets now find the contours of the image
# # find contours: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gradient, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("contours: ", len(contours))
print("hierachy: ", len(hierarchy))
print(hierarchy)


cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("contour image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Tips, help or code is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using the grayscale image, try converting to a different colorspace and explore the different channels (like HSV, LAB, etc.)

Comment: I have already tried with finding BGR colors, but the problem is that not every painting in the other pictures that I have have the same contour color.

Comment: In place of `cv2.RETR_TREE` use `cv2.EXTERNAL` Be sure your threshold etc has the paintings as white on a black background before finding contours. Display each result to be sure it is as expected and adjust parameters appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** We [load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/), [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image.
2. **Two pass dilation to merge contours.** At this point, we have a binary image but individual separated contours. Since we can assume that a painting is a single large square contour, we can merge small individual adjacent contours together to form a single contour. To do this, we create a vertical and horizontal kernel using [`cv2.getStructuringElement`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then [dilate](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to merge them together. Depending on the image, you may need to adjust the kernel sizes or number of dilation iterations.
3. **Detect paintings.** Now we [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and filter using [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) using a minimum threshold area to filter out small contours. Finally we obtain the [bounding rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) coordinates and draw the rectangle with [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle).

---

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (13,13), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Two pass dilate with horizontal and vertical kernel
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,9))
dilate = cv2.dilate(dilate, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, filter using contour threshold area, and draw rectangle
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 20000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 3):

So here is the actual size of the portrait frame.
So here is  small code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 37
#OpenCV 4.3.0, Raspberry Pi 3/B/4B-w/4/8GB RAM, Buster,v10.
#Date: 3rd, June, 2020

import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('portrait.jpeg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(img, 120,890)
# Apply adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)
thresh_color = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# apply some dilation and erosion to join the gaps - change iteration to detect more or less area's
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations = 50)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,None,iterations = 50)

# Find the contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,
                                      cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 20000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,
                      (x,y),(x+w,y+h),
                      (0,255,0),
                      2)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is output:
[image]